# Using multiple runners in one gitlab-ci pipeline action

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-deployment

I have a repository in GitLab with two connected runners. Each runner is on a different server. Each runner has a `test` tag.

Assuming my CICD pipeline is just one action:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
  - test
  script:
  - echo 'Deploying...'
```

How can I run it on both servers/runners at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every job is executed on a single runner. You cannot run a single job on multiple runners.

Additionally, if all runners use the same tag, there's no guarantee of which runner will pick up the job. If you create multiple jobs, they may all be run by a single runner.

To ensure a job runs a specific runner, the runner needs a **unique** tag. To run jobs on all the runners, you'll need as many jobs as you have runners, each configured to use the respective unique tag.

So, if each of your runners had a unique tag like `runner-1`, `runner-2`, `runner-3`, you might do something like this:

```yaml
myjob-dev:
  tags:
    - runner-1
  # ...

myjob-staging:
  tags:
    - runner-2
  # ...

myjob-production:
  tags:
    - runner-3
  # ...
```

You can condense the configuration using `parallel:matrix:` or `extends:` or similar [techniques to optimize](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html) the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix and parallel for every runner with different tags. But your next question will be how to control the runtime process of this matrix. And a special question will be how to ignore runners that are not currently available. Both questions has no answers and actually I've found that it is not possible today.

From my point of view current matrix and parallel is completely useless when you want to spawn job on every runner.